# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "ir camino a los pinos" para referir a morirse?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, historia, eufemismos

A veces he escuchado la expresión "irse para los pinos" en referencia a morirse. No sé si es una expresión regional o si la usan en varios países, pero no pude encontrar información de esta en internet. ¿Se sabe de dónde viene esta expresión?

Answer (score 3):

Aventuro que la expresión se relaciona con la existencia común de pinos en los cementerios como especie arbórea decorativa.

Sin saber si tenga un origen español, (soy de Argentina y personalmente nunca oí a la frase) si encontré que la expresión es una de las muchas formas con las que figuradamente se nombra al morir en la cultura cubana.

[Este artículo lista  la gran variedad de maneras, en los que en Cuba se alude a la muerte](http://www.cubarte.cult.cu/periodico-cubarte/diferentes-formas-de-morirse-en-cuba/), señalando entre ellas, el decir:

> *ir camino a los pinos*, para los corojos, para el tamarindo o para el mamey*

dependiendo de cuales sean las especies predominantemente plantadas en los cementerios de las distintas localidades.

(El corojo es [un árbol o variedad de Palma propia de Cuba](https://www.ecured.cu/Corojo), así como el [tamarindo](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamarindus_indica), —un frutal, propio del Sudán, de uso muy extendido en los trópicos—; o el [mamey](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammea_americana), también un frutal tropical)

---

PD: En [Mediterraneo](https://youtu.be/_w2WOHs9wG4), la hermosa canción del cantautor catalán Juan Manuel Serrat, se usa la figura [de los pinos](https://m.letras.mus.br/joan-manuel-serrat/538444/), al pedir ser enterrado en la ladera de un monte, con vista al mar

> *(...) En la ladera de un monte, más alto que el horizonte / 
>  Quiero tener buena vista /
> Mi cuerpo será camino / 
>  **Le daré verde a los pinos** y amarillo a la genista. / 
>  Cerca del mar, porque yo nací en el Mediterráneo /  
> (...)*

Comment: A lo mejor no sea muy conocida, pero soy de Argentina y mi abuelo la decía

Comment: Solo una suposición. Dado que la madera de pino se usa frecuentemente para hacer ataúdes, ¿podría la expresión provenir más bien de algo como "ir camino de la caja de pino"? Es decir, ¿podría referirse "los pinos" a las "cajas de pino" que pueblan los cementerios? En España, por cierto, el árbol típico de los cementerios es el ciprés.